# How do i implement this delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates, inline-functions

Action doesnt seem to support params string[] as a param so i wrote

```
delegate void WriteFn(string s, params string[] ls);
```

i have this function

```
void blah(WriteFn Write, string fmt, params string[] a)
```

Now i would like to write an function but i cant seem to figure the syntax out. It something like

```
{
    var sw = ...
    blah(new WriteFn(s, ls) { sw.write(s, ls); }, fmt, a);
    //not what i want to do but close enough. remember sw isnt a param in WriteFn
```

How do i write this?

Comment: What is `sw.write()`'s method signature?

Comment: The code inside the {} doesnt matter (pretend its blank). I cant get the codeblock as a param to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear. Are we suppose to guess that `sw` is a `StreamWriter`? If so, it looks like this would work:

```
blah((s, ls) => sw.Write(s, ls), fmt, a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do this because variable argument lists is **NOT** compatible with anonymous methods, according to [MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1hskazt.aspx)